# Effect of medium on wave propagation in closed pipes

Tags: waves

I am wondering, if one were to build a speaking tube, would it be better to fill it with water or air?  This is including any losses for conducting the sound energy from air to the water.

A speaking tube was just a pipe filled with air used on some ships and in some homes.  While it's obsolete tech, I was curious about why they used air.  A simple matter of cost, or was water an inferior solution?  In general does the density of the medium have an effect on signal loss or signal degradation?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have significant losses with water due to impedance mismatch. If you had water (or any other medium), due to the difference in acoustic impedance you'd get reflections of sound waves at each medium interface. That's why, for example, it's hard to hear any sounds from above water when you're underwater. This would cause huge losses in sound energy. I'm sure the other reasons, such as cost and lack of feasibility play a role, but are probably less so a consideration than the impedance mismatch and energy loss issue.

Answer (score 0):

Water would cause distortion of the human voice, as well as being an unneeded source of possible leak. I am guessing what might have prompted your question was the idea that water transmits sounds longer distances, but I have a feeling this only affects very low frequency sounds,  such as whale songs, which are are at a level we cannot hear or produce.